# How to handle fetch API request with express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api, httpbackend

I want to send request using **fetch API** and want to handle those request with **Express JS**.

I have created **server.js** (express JS), **index.html** (home page) and **signin.html** (signin page).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> <center>Welcome</center> </h1>
    <center> <button onclick="login()">Signin</button> </center>
</body>

<script>
    function login() 
    {   
        fetch('./signin.html')
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));        
    }   
</script>

</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
}); 

app.get('/signin.html', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'signin.html'));
}); 

app.listen(8080);
```

I want when user **click the Sign in button, `fetch api` send a request to **`server.js`** file and **`server.js`** send back response to `fetch api` and render the response to the browser**.

Is it possible?

Comment: Use a [validator](https://validator.nu/). There is no `<center>` any more. We've had CSS for presentation for over two decades.

Comment: You could try shifting the fetch api code to the server side (button enclosed in a form) or an <a> tag

Answer (score 2):

The *entire point* of Ajax is that the response is handled by your JavaScript and **not** by navigating to a new page.

Now, you *could* [push a new URL into the history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) and [replace the entire DOM of the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) with the new data, but it would be, in relative terms, hugely complex and fiddly.

Just use a regular link and don't involve client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Actually my plan is to send authentication token with every DB query request and verify the token first then perform the query.

Comment: Use a cookie for that if you are dealing with whole pages.

Comment: So, can you tell me a way how to send authentication token to the server with headers?

Comment: But, if I use cookie then how to add headers to a request? How to send the request to the server?

Comment: The login response would include a `Set-Cookie` header. Then the browser will send a `Cookie` header on subsequent requests.